# thymeleaf bind both input and label to object

Tags: forms, thymeleaf

Given that's it's proper to bind labels to input values, ie:

```
<label for="username">Your name</label> 
<input type="text" id="username" />
```

I would like Thymeleaf to also add the `for` field to the `label` matching the `id` used in the `input`. It probably has support for this, but the obvious is failing me.

Given something like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addAddress}" method="post" th:object="${address}">
    <label th:for="*{street}">Street</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{street}"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Html output created is as such (missing the `for` field inside the `label`.

```
<form action="/addAddress" method="post">
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" value=""/>
```

Can thymeleaf generate a `for` field to use inside the `label` that matches the `id` used inside `input`?

I know I can wrap `label` around `input` but would rather not go that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just overload the `id` attribute set by `th:field`.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addAddress}" method="post" th:object="${address}">
    <label for="street">Street</label>
    <input id="street" type="text" th:field="*{street}"/>
    ...
</form>
```

If you fear id collisions, thymeleaf has a bunch of id generation utilities:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#ids

Beware of the fact `th:field` behave quite differently from other thymeleaf attributes. It does 3 things :

- Set html `value` attribute to the value of the street field from your object (this is not very unusual, works the same as `th:value="*{street}"`
- Set both the `id` and `name` html attribute to the *name* (NOT the value) of the street field street. This is NOT the same as `th:id="*{street}"`, which would use the value of the field street.

Comment: Thanks Jean! I'm sorry, I did a terrible job of explaining myself. I wanted thymeleaf to also add the `id` field to `label` so it would reference the proper `input` field. Just re-worded the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You don't need thymeleaf here, just add `for` and `id` like in my exemple! If you really need to for some reason, you can use `th:for="'street'"` and `th:id="'street'"` (you need the `'` inside the `"`)

Comment: Hi Jean, many thanks for your time! That is definitly a possibility. What I was trying to do, though, was to have Thymeleaf generate the for and the id automatically based on the ID. It was just a minor convenience for me as I wouldn't have to type that field, and it would auto-change based on the object's name.

Comment: It never autochange, sadly. In your exemple, you use `th:field="*{street}"`, but if you rename your `street` field to, say, `address` in the Java object, you will have to change the template yourself.

Comment: Hi Jean, sorry... I'm really having a hard time passing what I wanted accross. Say I add an <input> with `th:field="*{street}"` it will create `id="street" name="street"` I would like to also be able to do, on a <label> field `th:for="*{street}"` and have Thymeleaf create `for="street"` automatically. It's really a minor issue... but just to make things consistent. If the ID and NAME of the <input> field are auto-generated, I would also like to have the FOR field of the <label> be auto-generated.

Comment: Why is `th:for="*{street}"` better than `for="street"`? Autogeneration, as you call it, just removes a few unnecessary characters. Really I think the best is to overcharge the id generated by`th:field` so that you don't need to change the `for` from your label if you rename the field, and so that you avoid possible duplicated id.

Comment: When I write `*{street}` the IDE auto checks if the field is valid. Thus, there's less human error. When refactoring multiple fields on multiple forms, it's easy to miss a "for" in a label, as the error won't be really noticeable.

Comment: Oh I see. My IDE doesn't do that. If you overload the id though you can change the field name but keep the id the same, si that's a potential solution?